# Getting element inside other element by class php DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

Hi Guys i do have this Html Code :

```
<div class="post-thumbnail2">
   <a href="http://example.com" title="Title">
       <img src="http://linkimgexample/image.png" alt="Title"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of src image (http://linkimgexample/image.png) and the value of the href link (http://example.com) using php DOMDocument

what i did to get the link was something like that :

```
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");

    foreach($divs as $div) { 
        $cl = $div->getAttribute("class");

        if ($cl == "post-thumbnail2") {
            $links = $div->getElementsByTagName("a");
            foreach ($links as $link)
                    echo $link->getAttribute("href")."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

i could do the same for src img

```
$imgs = $div->getElementsByTagName("img"); 
foreach ($imgs as $img)
    echo $img->getAttribute("src")."<br/>";
```

but sometime in the website there is no image and the Html code is like that :

```
 <div class="post-thumbnail2">
   <a href="http://example.com" title="Title"></a>
</div>
```

so my questions is how could i get the 2 value at the same time it means when there is no image i show some message

to be more clear this is an example :

```
<div class="post-thumbnail2">
       <a href="http://example1.com" title="Title">
           <img src="http://linkimgexample/image1.png" alt="Title"/>
       </a>
    </div>
<div class="post-thumbnail2">
       <a href="http://example2.com" title="Title"></a>
</div>
<div class="post-thumbnail2">
       <a href="http://example3.com" title="Title">
           <img src="http://linkimgexample/image2.png" alt="Title"/>
       </a>
</div>
```

i want the result to be

```
http://example1.com - http://linkimgexample/image1.png
http://example2.com - there is no image here !
http://example3.com - http://linkimgexample/image2.pn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DOMElement::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), that means you can find out if a `img`-element was found by checking the `length` property.

```
$imgs = $div->getElementsByTagName("img"); 
if($imgs->length > 0) {
    foreach ($imgs as $img)
        echo $img->getAttribute("src")."<br/>";
} else {
    echo "there is no image here!<br/>";
}
```

You should think about using [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) - it makes your life traversing the DOM a bit easier:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if($doc->loadHtml($xmlData)) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
    $postThumbLinks = $xpath->query("//div[@class='post-thumbnail2']/a");

    foreach($postThumbLinks as $link) {
        $imgList = $xpath->query("./img", $link);

        $imageLink = "there is no image here!";

        if($imgList->length > 0) {
            $imageLink = $imgList->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
        }

        echo $link->getAttribute('href'), " - ", $link->getAttribute('title'),
             " - ", $imageLink, "<br/>", PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "can't load HTML document!", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! when i use XPath i don't get the imageLink i am still trying to make it work could you please explain to me this part : 
what's the difference between $imgList = $xpath->query("//img", $link); and $imgList = $xpath->query("./img", $link);

Comment: Well `//img` returns recursively all image elements under the document root, which is probably not what you want since that would make $imageLink always point to the src of the first `<img>` element in your document. You probably want to use `.//img` (notice the point at the start which denotes the current node), which searches for the img elements under the current node (which is provided via the second parameter of `query`). `./img` only returns the img elements which are direct child elements of the a-element.